# Is SASS not able to combine content?

Tags: css, sass

I just noticed that SASS doesn't seem able to combine same content groups. Take this as an example:

```
#my-id {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#my-id {
  color: red;
}
```

This piece renders into the following *.css*:

```
#my-id {
  font-size: 20px; }

#my-id {
  color: red; }
```

Instead I expected this behaviour:

```
#my-id {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px; }
```

Is there some flag/option to turn this clever combination on/off? This would be especially useful when including one *basic* stylesheet, which gives basic elements some set state and manipulate the elements after this inclusion.

Comment: Try to compile you SCSS at http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/ this will merge the css of same selectors. I don't see a way in scss compiler

Comment: @A.J Compile SASS to css via SASS-Compiler. Paste it on the page and convert back to SASS. Compile the new SASS again?